# Error while installing safesquid

Tags: dependencies

When i try to install safesquid i get error message "libldap_r.so.2 => not found",
 How can i solve it ?

I am using RHEL 5

I installed squid 2.6 stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this post help you? -
http://www.safesquid.com/html/viewtopic.php?p=12604#12604

Comment: @sachinpurohit, I tried. But still problem continuing

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the compat-openldap RPM

Comment: @Dominik , Not working